# Can I upload two web applications on the same web domain using ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications

Is it possible to publish two web applications on the same webdomain?
Currently when I try to do this, it gives 500 server error.

Also, these two web apps will have two different webconfig files. So is that okay?

I plan to publish these two web applications not in root but in seperate folders other than root.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. They should also run in separate application pools. They should both be written in the same version of .Net that is being run in the root directory. If there is a difference, you may run into web.config errors regarding unsupported keys. Preferably if there must be a difference, you will want the newer version to be in the sub-folder since backwards compatibility will allow deprecated elements to be tolerated.

**Edit:**
Also: Each sub-folder will need to be configured as a separate "Virtual Directory" and run with a separate application name. If they share an application pool and potentially an application name, you may have object collisions and memory usage problems.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I believe if I put them in seperate folders other than root then the two webconfigs will be in these folders. Do I need to keep one webconfig in root?

Comment: @meetpd: You don't need to, no. But keep in mind that the root will still be configured to "run" in a version of .Net and that version will have a machine.config and a global web.config which may clash with your sub-folders. I also forgot one other thing that I will add as an edit to my answer.